# Membership testing of floats in Pandas int64 dataframe produces unexpected result

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, inclusion

I have a Pandas dataframe, named "impression_data," which includes a column called "site.id," like this:

```
   >>> impression_data['site.id']

0      62
1     189
2     191
3      62
...
```

Each item in this column has the datatype numpy.int64, like this:

```
>>> for i in impression_data['site.id']:
    print type(i)

<type 'numpy.int64'>
<type 'numpy.int64'>
<type 'numpy.int64'>
...
```

And as expected, membership testing works well so long as I test integers:

```
>>> 62 in impression_data['site.id']
True
```

But here's the unexpected result: I was under the impression that a column of `np.int64`'s ought not to include any decimal values whatsoever. Apparently I'm wrong. What's going on here?

```
>>> 62.5 in impression_data['site.id']
True
```

---

Edit 1:
All values in the column ought to be integers by construction. For completeness, I have also performed the following casting operation and encountered no errors:

```
impression_data['site.id'] = impression_data['site.id'].astype('int')
```

As per @BremBam's suggestions in the comments, I tried

```
impression_data['site.id'].map(type).unique()
```

which produces

```
[<type 'numpy.int64'>]
```

A minimal example and the real datafile I'm working with are here
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28347262/SE%20Pandas%20Int64%20Membership%20Testing/cm_impression.csv

and here

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28347262/SE%20Pandas%20Int64%20Membership%20Testing/ExampleCode.py

Comment: Are you sure every single value is an int?  What does `impression_data['site.id'].map(type).unique()` give?  Can you provide example code and data that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, @BrenBarn. I took your advice on trying `impression_data['site.id'].map(type).unique()` and edited my question to reflect that. Example code and data to follow shortly.

Comment: Historically using `in` for numpy arrays can produce odd results- I would suggest something like `np.any(df['site.id'].isin([62.5]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a bug in pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5591).  The value is cast to the type of the index before the containment test is done, so `62.5` is converted to `62`.  (Note that `in` for a Series checks whether the value is in the *index*, not the values.)

I believe you can get what you want by doing `62.5 in impression_data.values`.

Comment: `62.5 in impression_data['site.id'].values` produces `False`, just as you predict. An easy fix!

Comment: @avn2109 Please note using `in` with numpy arrays does not always produce the desired result especially when the numpy array has more then one dimension. Be very careful of this.

Comment: @Ophion: Can you be more specific?  In any case, here we're only using a 1D array (in the form of a Series).

Answer (score 0):

First, membership tests in Series are of the *index*, not the *values*:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([10,20,30])
>>> s
0    10
1    20
2    30
dtype: int64
>>> 0 in s
True
>>> 10 in s
False
```

But you're right:

```
>>> 1.5 in s
True
```

After some work, this seems to be because of `__contains__` in `Int64HashTable`:

```
cdef class Int64HashTable: #(HashTable):
    [...]
    def __contains__(self, object key):
        cdef khiter_t k
        k = kh_get_int64(self.table, key)
        return k != self.table.n_buckets
```

`key` comes in as a float, but we have

```
inline khint_t kh_get_int64(kh_int64_t*, int64_t)
```

and so I think it's coerced to an integer before the comparison is made.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake with the index, @DSM. That could cause a lot of problems.